# why is mandrill send_at with php is sending right away

Tags: php, mandrill

I have a script that prepares an email and then schedules it to send 24 hours later... I call the Mandrill API

```
$mandrill->messages->sendTemplate($template_name, $template_content, $message, (string)$send_at);
```

and the send_at value is 2016-09-15 09:09:28 or whatever in the future.

The email triggers right away though!! How do I get it to send 24 hours in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a UTC timestamp?
Have proper credit on file to use this feature?

Send at documentation from https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html:
when this message should be sent as a UTC timestamp in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format. If you specify a time in the past, the message will be sent immediately. An additional fee applies for scheduled email, and this feature is only available to accounts with a positive balance.
Validation: datetime

Comment: yes, we are a pay as you go customer and have a credit card on file. Ant the time stampe is in UTC format 2016-09-15 09:09:28

Comment: are you using that code above verbatim?  Drop dropping the (string) before send at and just put in '2016-09-16 09:09:28'

Comment: yes and no, I tried removing (string) and it didn't work either.